# Aurelia add bootstrap tab dynamically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, aurelia

Within my aurelia app I have a navbar-based menu system and a bootstrap tab. Whenever I select a menu item, a new pane gets appended to the tab, showing the content/view that belongs to the selected menu item. I am fetching that content/view from the server (MVC).

```
  $('.tab-content').append(`<div class="tab-pane" id="tab${menuItem.id}" role="tabpanel"></div>`);
    ... // fetch view from server
   $(tab).html('fetched content');
```

This works fine as long as 'fetched content' is pure string. However, once I am fetching an Aurelia view (like '

```html
<template>some content</template>
```

'), then the browser wraps the fetched content with "#document-fragment" and the content is not shown.

I am an Aurelia newbie, so I suspect I am missing something fundamental here. What do I need to do to make this work?

P.S. I have also tried enhancing the templating engine after setting the html, but to no avail.

Comment: Enhancing should have worked, but regardless if it works or not, I think you should avoid fetching components from the server. The server and the client should be independent from each other.

Comment: Why are you using jQuery to append HTML instead of using Aurelia to do this?

Answer (score 0):

After considerable head-scratching I have realized that both comments are pointing in the right direction and that my approach was flawed. Flawed on two accounts: Firstly, I was violating the MVVM concept by adding a DOM element (the tab pane) directly rather than adding to the viewmodel and let Aurelia handle the heavy lifting. Secondly, I was attempting to bypass Aurelia's routing mechanism by going directly to the server and getting my view from there. No wonder I had problems... I have gone back to the drawing board.

Thx for your support, guys.

Comment: P.S. https://gist.run/?id=b3df9d740a3cf3d31098c83c9ffe8614 shows a working sample for precisely the situation I was struggling with.